# How to get a bytes value from a bytes saved as string in Airflow connection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, airflow

I'm saving a Google Drive token in Airflow connections this way:

```py
b'\x80\x03cgoogle.oauth2 ...
```

I have the following code to recover the token from the connections:

```py
drive_conn = BaseHook.get_connection("drive_api")
token = drive_conn.password
```

And I wanted to recover this token in a `bytes` format, which is required for my following code to work:

```py
token = pickle.loads(token)
```

However it is stored as `str`.

Can I recover that as `bytes`? Or how can I convert to bytes? Or there is other way to store this token? convert to `str` before, maybe?

I tried:

`token.decode()`

However I get the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately I needed sent a file with my tokens to Airflow source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into this myself just now, for tokens that AirFlow stores as binary, you need to run `ast.literal_eval` to convert them back to the native types first.  This should work for you:

```
drive_conn = BaseHook.get_connection("drive_api")
token = ast.literal_eval(drive_conn.password)
```

Keep in mind this will throw an exception if the input data cannot be parsed.